# WPF: Cannot set the converter - error when starting the app

Tags: wpf

I want to set the `TextBlock` to visible/collapsed mode depending on the binded value. It doesn't work and I get this message when I want to debug my app:

> Set property 'System.Windows.Data.Binding.Converter' threw an exception.

The value that gets binded is of type `Uri`. There is an inner `InvalidCastException` that says:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter'.

Here's my converter:

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string && string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else if (value == null)
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And here's the XAML that throws the exception:

```
...
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Visibility="{Path=UrlAddress, Converter=visibilityConverter}">
    This never works!
</TextBlock>
...
```

Help, please!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try referencing your converter as a StaticResource

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=UrlAddress, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
```

Comment: Congrats on a first answer ;)

Comment: @Sinatr I think 46 people found the answer of referencing the converter via a StaticResource helped them.  Thanks for pointing out the missing keyword though, I'll update.

Comment: Why does this fix it.. It works, but I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

forgot to mention Binding Markup Extension with ElementName attribute maybe?

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ElementName=XXX, Path=UrlAddress, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">  `
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
 <TextBlock Visibility="{Path=UrlAddress, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">`
```